# my fileSystem readStream callback is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I'm trying to create an REST API using node.js express, for an anime site but my function to upload the videos is not working and idk why, some variables are in portugues(my first language) so i can post in the comment the english version if it would help

this is my controller to test the funtion

```
    const atendimento = require('../models/atendimento')

module.exports = app => {
    app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {

        const episodio = req.body
        atendimento.Testafuncao(episodio)
            .then(data => res.status(200).json(data))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ err }))
    })
}
```

the funtion in models

```
Testafuncao(episodio) {
        uploadDeArquivos(episodio.caminho, episodio.nome, (err, resultado => {
            if (err) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    reject(err)
                })
            } else {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    resolve(resultado)
                })
            }
        }))
    }
```

and finally the function that read and write the file

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = (caminho, NomeArquivo, callBackVideoUpado) => {

    const tipo = path.extname(caminho)
    const tiposValidos = ['avi', 'mp4', 'm4v', 'mov', 'wmv', 'mpg', 'mpeg']
    const tipoEhValido = tiposValidos.indexOf(tipo.substring(1)) !== -1

    if (tipoEhValido) {
        const newPath = `./assets/koba/${NomeArquivo}${tipo}`

        fs.createReadStream(caminho)
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(newPath))
            .on('finish', () => callBackVideoUpado(false, newPath))
    } else {
        const err = 'Erro, tipo de arquivo invalido'
        console.log(err)
        callBackVideoUpado(err)
    }


}
```

the 'err' variable in uploadDeArquivo's callback is undefined and IDK why